# Facing some issue in Data Binding (error: illegal start of expression ? resourceData = null;)

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

My XML code is below

```
    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <import type="com.example.data.api.Status" />

        <variable
            name="resource"
            type="com.example.data.api.Resource" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp8"
        android:visibility="@{resource.data == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" //This line throwing error
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:visibility="@{resource.status == Status.LOADING ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/error_msg"
            android:text="@{resource.message ?? @string/unknown_error}"
            android:visibility="@{resource.status == Status.ERROR ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

using this code, I got below error

```
error: illegal start of expression            ? resourceData = null;
```

If I remove the below line then everything works fine.

```
android:visibility="@{resource.data == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

Resource class is handling the API data that is taking a generic type parameter and it can be null anytime. Resource class is below:

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(msg: String, data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.ERROR, data, msg)
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(Status.LOADING, data, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me about why this line throwing error. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Also add code of `Resource` class

Comment: now updated `Resource` class :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Resource` class is generic type and you try to use generic property, you have to set the type in XML, Otherwise it shows `illegal start of expression`.

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="resource"
        type="com.example.data.api.Resource&lt;String>" />
</data>
```

Here I have used `String` as generic type: `Resource<String>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could solve it avoiding the `resource.data == null`

Instead I created a new method in the Resource class that makes the comparison and finally the XML line looks like:  `resource.isDataNull`